# lightning-record-picker filter not working?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using lightning-record-picker in my lwc component to select subsource object records. below is the code. Source__c is lookup filed.

lwc.html

```
<lightning-record-picker label="Select a record" placeholder="Search..." object-api-name="Custom_SubSource__c" filter={filter}>
                                </lightning-record-picker>
```

in the console this.selectedSourceId getting id also.

filter condition is below:

```
    filter = {
    criteria: [
        {
            fieldPath: "Source__c",
            operator: "eq",
            value: "this.selectedSourceId",
        }
    ],
}
```

I am not getting any records

Comment: You have not shared all the details. Share your code using which you are getting the picklist values.
And follow https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to post a better question.